# Twisted work with Python 3.3?

Tags: twisted

i use py3.3.2 and Twisted 15 on win7 and get this error

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\coder\Desktop\s.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, endpoints
  File "D:\Python33\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\protocol.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import interfaces, error, defer
  File "D:\Python33\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 29, in <module>
    from twisted.python import lockfile, log, failure
  File "D:\Python33\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\lockfile.py", line 52, in <module>
    _open = file
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/7626 - A ticket opened about this issue

Answer (score 3):

Twisted does not currently have continuous integration for Windows on Python 3; the only supported platform with Python 3 test coverage is Ubuntu.  Please file a bug at https://twistedmatrix.com/.

In the meanwhile, please use Python 2.7 for Windows to use Twisted there.